# TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I was visualising a dataset of election polls and requires to use the data of october 2012 but its giving me an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np
poll_df=pd.read_csv('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv')
row_in=0
xlimit=[]
for date in poll_df['Start Date']:
    if date[0:7] == '2012-10':
        xlimit.append(row_in)
        row_in += 1
    else:
        row_in+=1
print(min(xlimit))
print(max(xlimit))
```

why is it giving me this error and what does  it mean?

Comment: It means `date[0:7]` doesn't make sense; that column contains timestamps, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
url ='http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv'
```

**Solution with datetimes** - convert column to `date`s in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then compare strings by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
poll_df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Start Date'])

df = poll_df[poll_df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m') == '2012-10']

print(df['Start Date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

**Solution with strings** - extract first 7 values by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
poll_df = pd.read_csv(url)

df = poll_df[poll_df['Start Date'].str[:7] == '2012-10']

print(df['Start Date'].dtype)
object
```

---

```
print(df.head())

                Pollster Start Date    End Date  Entry Date/Time (ET)  \
18                YouGov 2012-10-31  2012-11-03  2012-11-04T16:24:50Z   
19                   Pew 2012-10-31  2012-11-03  2012-11-04T15:46:59Z   
21             Rasmussen 2012-10-31  2012-11-02  2012-11-03T10:54:09Z   
22     Purple Strategies 2012-10-31  2012-11-01  2012-11-02T12:31:41Z   
23  JZ Analytics/Newsmax 2012-10-30  2012-11-01  2012-11-02T22:57:27Z   

    Number of Observations     Population             Mode  Obama  Romney  \
18                 36472.0  Likely Voters         Internet   49.0    47.0   
19                  2709.0  Likely Voters       Live Phone   48.0    45.0   
21                  1500.0  Likely Voters  Automated Phone   48.0    48.0   
22                  1000.0  Likely Voters       IVR/Online   47.0    46.0   
23                  1030.0  Likely Voters         Internet   48.0    46.0   

    Undecided  Other                                       Pollster URL  \
18        3.0    NaN  http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/p...   
19        NaN    3.0  http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/p...   
21        2.0    1.0  http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/p...   
22        7.0    NaN  http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/p...   
23        6.0    NaN  http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/p...   

                                           Source URL     Partisan  \
18  http://cdn.yougov.com/r/1/ygTabs_november_like...  Nonpartisan   
19  http://www.people-press.org/2012/11/04/obama-g...  Nonpartisan   
21  http://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content...  Nonpartisan   
22  http://www.purplestrategies.com/wp-content/upl...  Nonpartisan   
23                        http://www.jzanalytics.com/      Sponsor   

   Affiliation  Question Text  Question Iteration  
18        None            NaN                   1  
19        None            NaN                   1  
21        None            NaN                   1  
22        None            NaN                   1  
23         Rep            NaN                   1
```

Comment: Thanks for that but when i do this it starts giving me the error as **min() arg is an empty sequence** now what should i do?

Comment: @Ben.hardy - Waht is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version 0.23.0

Comment: it is giving me this-> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence on the statement  print(min(xlimit))

Comment: @Ben.hardy - But why need it? I dont use it in my answer. What you are expected from `min(xlimit))` ?

Comment: Actually i need to plot all the variations occured only in the october month of 2012 so for that i am counting the 30 rows so that i can use them in xlim for plotting.

Comment: Maybe you can use pandas for ploting like `df.plot('Start Date', 'Number of Observations')`, check also [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)